# simulación de juego de dados en C

Tags: c, funciones

vengo acá con un simulador de juego de dados con solamente un solo dado, utilizando un array que identifique a cada jugador y una función randon que simula el tiro del dado, más con una opción de ingresar el 0 para salir del programa, el único problema es que cuando ejecuto este código en la página programiz usando solamente C, me sale el siguiente error en el output

```
ERROR!
gcc /tmp/iRL5JTRTZn.c -lm
/tmp/iRL5JTRTZn.c: In function 'main':
/tmp/iRL5JTRTZn.c:29:21: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
   29 |         puntajes[i] = tirarDado(numJugadores);
      |                     ^
```

esto de acá, es el código entero que trate de hacer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void tirarDado(int numJugadores) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int puntaje = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numJugadores; i++) {
        puntaje = puntaje + (rand() % 6 + 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int numJugadores;
    int puntajes[numJugadores];
    char nombres[numJugadores][20];
    int jugadorGanador, i;

    printf("Ingresa el número de jugadores: ");
    scanf("%i", &numJugadores);

    for (i = 0; i < numJugadores; i++) {
        printf("Ingresa el nombre del jugador %i: ", i);
        scanf("%s", nombres[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numJugadores; i++) {
        puntajes[i] = 0;
        puntajes[i] = tirarDado(numJugadores);
        printf("El jugador %s tuvo un puntaje de %i\n", nombres[i], puntajes[i]);
    }

    jugadorGanador = i;
    for (i = 0; i < numJugadores; i++) {
        if (puntajes[i] > jugadorGanador) {
            jugadorGanador = i;
        }
    }

    printf("El jugador que gana es: %s\n", nombres[jugadorGanador]);

    return 0;
}
```

que estoy haciendo mal? por favor díganme lo que sea, cualquier ayuda, y lo corrijo enseguida, espero respuestas muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, tu función ***tirarDado*** esta definida como void, por lo que esperas que no devuelva nada, pero en el momento que pones:

```
puntajes[i] = tirarDado(numJugadores);
```

tu función deberá devolver algo necesariamente, para ser precisos un entero, ya que puntajes esta definido como un arreglo de enteros, modifica la función de esta manera:

```
int tirarDado(int numJugadores) {
    int puntaje = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numJugadores; i++) {
        puntaje = puntaje + (rand() % 6 + 1);
    }
    return puntaje;
}
```

Despues es mejor definir la semilla para tu numero aleatorio fuera de la función, si la defines dentro de la funcion obtendras el mismo numero aleatorio (mas info [aqui](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5323258/Srand-function-not-working-and-rand-function-givin)):

```
int main() {
    int numJugadores;
    int jugadorGanador = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
...
... // otras lineas de codigo
```

Ademas defines estas variables:

```
int puntajes[numJugadores];
char nombres[numJugadores][20];
```

en un momento de la ejecución del programa donde ***numJugadores*** no esta definida (porque se necesita que el usuario lo especifique), mueve esas definiciones después de que el usuario haya definido ***numJugadores***

Después hice algunas pequeñas correcciones, como eliminar la variable 'i' y definir las variables 'i' de los fors localmente, el código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int tirarDado(int numJugadores) {
    int puntaje = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numJugadores; i++) {
        puntaje = puntaje + (rand() % 6 + 1);
    }
    return puntaje;
}

int main() {
    int numJugadores;
    int jugadorGanador = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Ingresa el número de jugadores: ");
    scanf("%i", &numJugadores);
    
    char nombres[numJugadores][20];
    int puntajes[numJugadores];

    for (int i = 0; i < numJugadores; i++) {
        printf("Ingresa el nombre del jugador %i: ", i);
        scanf("%s", nombres[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numJugadores; i++) {
        puntajes[i] = tirarDado(numJugadores);
        printf("El jugador %s tuvo un puntaje de %i\n", nombres[i], puntajes[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numJugadores; i++) {
        if (puntajes[i] > puntajes[jugadorGanador]) {
            jugadorGanador = i;
        }
    }

    printf("El jugador que gana es: %s\n", nombres[jugadorGanador]);

    return 0;
}
```

Probado en Programiz y en otros IDE's online.

Comment: ya lo tengo,aunque no queria tanto usar el codigo que vos me diste,ya que queria cambiar el que comparti agregando otras cosas,asi que gracias por los detalles te lo re agradezco